# Lua 5.3 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to implement lua into C++ however I am having problems with Visual Studio saying that I have an unresolved external symbol called "_sprintf", "_fprintf", and "__iob_func".

I'm pretty sure that these functions exist in C++ since I have seen (well the first 2) them used before.

Comment: Lua is written in C. Don't try to compile it as C++.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, Lua can be definitely be compiled as C++.

Comment: @lhf as in "correctly"? (I do understand that its C API is usable from C++.) – even if so, I would still strongly disrecommend it. C and C++ are two different languages, and treating code written in one language as if it were written in another one is definitely bad practice.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - The man under the nickname "lhf" is one of Lua's authors.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get this working, or to atleast get Lua 5.3 into C++? I am porting a game engine originally designed in C# and it uses lua as a scripting language, so it would be nice to keep that same standard in C++ as well.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The [section about installing Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html) explicitly states that "Lua also compiles unmodified as C++", so please don't give that advice. No one made the statement that they are the same language. And no, Lua is not the only library that behaves well in this case, on purpose.

Comment: @mkluwe OK, cool, but "please don't give that advice" – why? it doesn't work in the general case… not everyone worries about their C code being also valid C++ code (and rightfully so).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Because you are not commenting in the general case! This is Lua, it explicitly supports C++ compilation (yay for exception support!) and in this context, you are simply spreading confusion with that statement.

Comment: @Stigma I'm afraid that it's *you* who are spreading confusion. You are trying to overgeneralize a specific phenomenon, which doesn't work.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I am not sure whether you are a troll or not. Regardless, my comment was referring to your very first statement regarding Lua: "Lua is written in C. Don't try to compile it as C++." Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @Stigma I am not a troll; I simply can't stand people giving bad advice in public. I reckon that Lua can be compiled as C++; and I **still** do advise against doing so. Just because you can doesn't mean you should!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running into the C-runtime changes introduced in VS2015: [The Great C Runtime Refactoring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/10/the-great-crt-refactoring.aspx).

You can add the following library to supply those definitions in the Additional Dependencies in the Project Settings -> Linker -> Input:

```
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
```

Comment: thanks, I had actually figured it out with the help of a friend. In addition to what you suggested (just incase someone else encounters a similar problem) I had to also have this line: FILE __iob_func[3] = { *stdin,*stdout,*stderr }; inside of the extern "C"{} block and I was able to compile with no problems.